Error verifying Solana signin on Nodejs server
I'm trying to setup a basic signin service using nodejs on the backend.
The backend is simple, I send a nonce to the FE, use the signin method, send the output to the nodejs server and try to validate using verifySignIn.
I'm however getting an error when trying to validate the signin: TypeError: The "list" argument must be an instance of SharedArrayBuffer, ArrayBuffer or ArrayBufferView.
Below is some code:
FE:
import type { SolanaSignInInput } from '@solana/wallet-standard-features';
import { verifySignIn } from '@solana/wallet-standard-util';

let nonce;

try {
  let response = await fetch(`http://localhost:3001/api/nonce/${publicKey}`, { method: 'GET' });
  if (!response.ok) throw new Error(`Failed to get nonce: ${response.statusText}`);
    let data = await response.json()
    nonce = data.nonce;
} catch (error: any) {
  throw new Error(`Failed to get nonce: ${error?.message}`);
}

  const input: SolanaSignInInput = {
    domain: window.location.host,
    address: publicKey ? publicKey.toBase58() : undefined,
    statement: 'Please sign in.',
    nonce: nonce
  };

  const output = await signIn(input);

  // send input and output to server
  let dataToVerify = {
    input: input,
    output: output
  }

  try {
    let response = await fetch(`http://localhost:3001/api/verifyv2/${publicKey}`, { 
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(dataToVerify)
    });
    if (!response.ok) throw new Error(`Failed to verify: ${response.statusText}`);
    let data = await response.json()
    console.log("verify response", data)
  } catch (error: any) {
    throw new Error(`Failed to verify: ${error?.message}`);
  }

BE (Where I have the issue verifying)
import { verifySignIn } from '@solana/wallet-standard-util';

router.post('/verifyv2/:address', (req, res) => {
  let address = req.params.address;
  let data = req.body;

  console.log("received request verify v2")
  console.log(address)
  console.log(data)

  console.log(!verifySignIn(data.input, data.output)) // This errors `TypeError: The "list" argument must be an instance of SharedArrayBuffer, ArrayBuffer or ArrayBufferView.`


  res.send();
})

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
